# Use profile on CiviEvent

Tags: civievent, profile

I've created a profile that I want to be able to use on all event. When I create an event, I don't see my custom profile. I've copied an already existing profile that worked before. But somehow, some of the 'Used for' options are greyed out, and I believe that is where the problem lies. Any help is appreciated.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Julie, In the profile listing the profile "name,email, bestelbonnumer" shows as including contribution fields. So won't show for event registration. 
https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/profiles/ If you want to show the profile field listing that would give us a chance to double check this.

Comment: Hi Craig, as you can see, i've added a pic of the fields that I use. There is indeed a contribution field, that I would use to let people insert an invoice number. This number is not actively linked or anything, it is simply as extra information. So perhaps there is another field in contact or individual that I can 'misuse'?

Comment: if you can explain the logic for wanting the Inv number on there, since civi has internal processes for creating an Invoice number and maybe you are trying to do something that civi can do automatically.

Comment: Thanks Julie.I've got the same question as Pete. Why are you asking the participant for an invoice number?

Comment: This is a client i'm working for where civicrm has been put in place by someone else. I'm not aware of why they want this invoice number, but i'm guessing it is simply for informational use. I've 'fixed' it by using the 'adress 3' field